# Name collision by module import in Angular 2 - is there a way to prevent it

Tags: angular, typescript, import, name-collision

I've almost caused a name collision, because I've created a class with common name `Message`, which already exists in PrimeNG:

```
import {Message} from "primeng/primeng";
import {Message} from "./dto";
```

Because it is my code, I could simply rename the class to anything else (like `MessageDTO`). But if this was the external class, I'd have an issue.

Is there any way to import class with alias, or any other mean to deal with name conflicts? I Java you can refer to class using fully qualified name instead of import, which looks ugly but is often unavoidable. How it looks like in Angular 2/TypeScript?

Comment: Set the compilerOption "moduleResolution" to "classic". in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As per `TypeScript` [import document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import) imports can also be renamed same as below :

```
import { Message } from "primeng/primeng";
import { Message as MessageDTO } from "./dto";
```